# I below code I use XSLX library for group my row with outline levels it is work with - sing but I want to do + sing with already collapsed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xlsx, xlsxwriter

I below code I use XSLX library for group my row with outline levels it is work with - sing but I want to do + sing with already collapsed.

```
let a = 4, b = 11;
for (let indexrow = 0; indexrow < printedDataOnExcel.length; indexrow++) {
    workSheet['!rows'] = workSheet['!rows'] || [];
    for (let rowIndex = a; rowIndex < b; rowIndex++) {
        workSheet['!rows'][rowIndex] = { level: 1, hidden: 1, hpt: 0 };
    }
    workSheet['!rows'][b] = { level: 0, hidden: 0, collapsed: 1 };
    a = b + 1;
    b = b + 8;
}
a = 4, b = 11;
```

Comment: Grouping with Xlsxwriter is covered in it's [documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_outlines.html?highlight=grouping). Not sure about the JavaScript bit though